# Returning True if a number is disarium

Tags: python

I'm doing a simple project where I need to return True or False based on if a number is disarium or not.

A number is said to be Disarium if the sum of its digits raised to their respective positions is the number itself.

ex.

```
is_disarium(135) ➞ True
# 1^1 + 3^2 + 5^3 = 1 + 9 + 125 = 135
```

My code:

```
def is_disarium(n):
    n2 = 0
    print(n)
    for x in range(len(str(n))):
        n2 += int(str(n)[x])**x+1
    return n == n2
```

But it doesn't work. I kinda tryed debugging it by printing out the variables.

Debugged version:

```
def is_disarium(n):
    n2 = 0
    print(n)
    for x in range(len(str(n))):
        n2 += int(str(n)[x])**x+1
        print(n2, n)
    return n == n2
```

For example when I run this: `is_disarium(6)`, the output is:

```
6
2 6
False
```

Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 4):

Change `int(str(n)[x])**x+1` to `int(str(n)[x])**(x+1)`. Remember order of operations.

Comment: Oh, I missed that. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `enumerate` over the `str` representation of the number to perform the exponentiation then `sum` that using a generator expression, such as

```
def is_disarium(num):
    return sum(int(val)**idx for idx, val in enumerate(str(num), 1)) == num
```

for example

```
>>> is_disarium(135)
True
>>> is_disarium(222)
False
```

Comment: Oh, that's a much shorter version, but it worked for me as well. Thanks!